# Show that to reduce the initial error by the factor $\varepsilon$ at most many iteration steps are required

Tags: numerical-methods, positive-definite, numerical-optimization, conjugate-gradient

> Consider the CG method for the iterative solution of the system of
> equations $A \mathrm{x}=\mathrm{b}$ with a positive definite and
> symmetric matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ and $b \in
>   \mathbb{R}^{n}$. Show that to reduce the initial error by the factor
> $\varepsilon$ at most $t(\varepsilon) \leq \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\kappa}
> > \log (2 / \varepsilon)+1$ many iteration steps are required. Here
> $\kappa$ is the spectral condition number of A.

If I understand correctly, the CG method has the property that the error after $\mathrm{t}$ iterations is orthogonal to the initial residual in the A-norm $\left(g^{t}=A\left(x^{*}-x^{t}\right)\right.$, where $x^{*}$ is the exact solution, $x^{t}$ is the approximate solution after $t$ iterations and $g^{t}$ is the residual after $\mathrm{t}$ iterations.

The A-norm of a vector $v$ is defined as $\|v\|_{A}=\sqrt{v^{T} A v}$ --> error after t iterations with respect to the A-norm: $\left\|x^{*}-x^{t}\right\|_{A}=\left\|g^{t}\right\|_{A}$

After $t$ iterations, the error is reduced by a factor of at least $\left(\frac{2}{1+\sqrt{\kappa}}\right)^{t}$:
$$\left\|x^{*}-x^{t}\right\|_{A} \leq \frac{2}{(1+\sqrt{\kappa})^{t}}\left\|x^{*}-x^{0}\right\|_{A}$$

Do I now have to set this inequality to $\varepsilon$ and solve for $\mathrm{t}$?
$$
\begin{array}{l}
\varepsilon \geq \frac{2}{(1+\sqrt{\kappa})^{t}} \\
t(\varepsilon) \leq \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\kappa} \log \left(\frac{2}{\varepsilon}\right)+1
\end{array}
$$

Can I proceed like this with my idea?

Comment: That is correct.